# Text input text is not shown unless it is focused in flex 4.6 android application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, android-emulator, flex4.6

I am developing an AIR application for android using flex 4.6 and air 3.1.In the application i have a view in which there is a textinput and a search button.After typing some text and clicking search button will take to the result view.From the result view user can go back to searchview by clicking back button.The `destructonPolicy` of SearchView is kept as `never` and I use `navigator.popView()` to go back to searchview.The problem is when I come back to search view the textinput is empty wherein it should show the txt that  was previously typed.But when  focus is on the textnput,the text appears. I want the text to be shown as soon as that view is shown again.Any idea why this issue is happening

**P.S-** This issue is  happening when  I check aftr installng the apk in an android emulator(OS 2.3.3).I dont have an android device to check this.So not sure if it is just an issue with emulator.If i use flex `4.5.1` sdk this issue is **not** happening

Here are the codes

Main mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.HomeView">
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

HomeView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView" destructionPolicy="never">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.pushView(ResultView);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:TextInput prompt="Enter some text"/>
    <s:Button label="Search" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:View>
```

ResultView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="ResultView">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.popView();

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="&lt;" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the issue exists on Flex 4.6; but not Flex 4.5 it is probably a side effect/redraw issue with the new default TextInput skins that use StageText.  I wrote a bit about that [here](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/5/1/Why-does-a-TextInput-appear-above-my-Popup-in-Flex-46).

In your 4.6 application, try setting the default Flex 4.5 skin:

```
<textInput skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin" />
```

Comment: Thank GOD for your suggestion. I had been debugging this very issue for a few hours before I came across this post. The text field worked fine for me in Flash Builder and on iOS. But, I had the above issue on Android devices. For what it's worth, one of the devices was running AIR 3.3.0.365 . I applied the skinClass to the text field and it immediately fixed the issue. Thanks again for posting!